# Returning specific items from an array given an array of coordinates in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, cell-array

Let's suppose I have some (numerical) array called `A_array` that is `N1xN2xN3` in size, and two more vector arrays `x = [x1,x2, ... ,xn]`, `y = [y1,y2, ... ,yn]` where `size(x) = size(y)`. 
`(where n < N1,N2,N3)`

Right now I'm trying to get the values in `A_array` at `(t,x1,y1)`, `(t,x2,y2)`, `etc.` so that the result is an array that looks like this: 
`[A_array(t,x1,y1), A_array(t,x2,y2), ... , A_array(t,xn,yn)]`

I tried writing `A_array(t,x,y)`, but this returns an `nxn` array, which is not what I would like.
I've tried to write out the problem into words to the best of my ability...
Could this also be generalized to multiple lists i.e. `x`,`y`,`z`,`etc.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)** as shown here -

```
A_array = A(sub2ind(size(A),repmat(t,1,numel(x)),x,y))
```

---

For higher dimensional array cases with `x`, `y`, `z`, `z2` etc. as the indexing arrays, just append them like this -

```
A_array = A(sub2ind(size(A),repmat(t,1,numel(x)),x,y,z,z2))
```

---

If `t` is used for indexing into some other dimension, like maybe the 3rd dimension -`[A_array(x1,y1,t), A_array(x2,y2,t), ... , A_array(xn,yn,t)]`, then change the position of `t` inside `sub2ind` accordingly. So, for this modified case you would have -

```
A_array = A(sub2ind(size(A),x,y,repmat(t,1,numel(x))))
```